# Typescript should every input parameter be an object with an interface, even when simple?

Tags: typescript, types, interface

Are typescript interfaces meant to be used in every possible input parameter? If not, what is the cutoff for when they should and should not be used.

For example, does it make sense to do this?

```
interface IOne {
   myFirstVal: string
}

interface ITwo {
   mySecondVal: number
}

function one (input: IOne) {
  const { myFirstVal } = input
  ...
}

function two (input: ITwo) {
  const { mySecondVal } = input
  ...
}
```

If the above does not make sense, then I assume I should just pass in primitives, like so:

`function one (myFirstVal: string) { ... }`

If the primitive should be used, what is the cutoff for when primitives should be used vs objects as defined in the first example?

Comment: It will all depend on the actions you are performing in the function. If your function just needs primitive i.e. `string` as input then it is not required to send a complete object as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think this just depends on the specific situation, and how you are building out your types in your program. Sometimes you will find that creating an interface or a type for something is necessary. For example if you were creating a type of a `Person`, that would be a good candidate for an interface. Since we can assume that they will have properties, and will be an object. Something like:

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    hobbies: string[];
    weight: number;
}
```

However, if we were just talking about a single value. Something like, a password. That would probably just be a primitive type. This is probably you could just type right in your program when you declare the variable. Something like:

```
let password: string = "my password";
```

In your example with `IOne` and `ITwo`, you would just have to think if those really need to be objects. Interface can only have one value, that is fine, however if they do only have one value, that is also a good time question it and see if you needed at all. Maybe you can just use the primitive type like you mentioned.

The goal of typescript is NOT to have interfaces for everything. It is to help your programs be more resilient, and help you catch bugs early as you develop.